# different servers and different loading time for angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have two different servers. On these servers I am deploying same jar which runs an Angular application. It is single page UI application.

On Server 1: My page loads within 2 seconds

On Server 2: .css files take 10 seconds & main.js takes almost 30 seconds to load.

I checked server 1 and server 2 configuration - they have similar ram and CPUs.

I looked out for angular optimization. We have used webpack-sources, prod flag,  uglifyJS and the issue still persists in the second server

I am not into front end much, please help me if possible -
can someone help , where it can be going wrong ...

Comment: Is the second server also slow with other pages?
You could run some other stuff to isolate the problem (server or angular problem).

Comment: juts the index page is slow , rest is all fine

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a networking speed/routing issue more than a server resource problem. Are the servers located in different parts of the world? I would check the upload speed between your local machine and the two servers.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i will check it definitely